# OrderBy inside EF linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have table `Sites` with related table `Photos`, `Photos` got FK on `SiteId`.
Photos can have value of field `PhotoNumber` equal 1, 2 or 3.
I need to get know if `Site` have any `Photos` with `PhotoNumber`  = 1, 2 and 3.
I try something like that, but i cant get how to order Photos by `Date` (`Date` is indexed field in `Photos`) inside of linq, to use `Any()` on ordered list, and ordered once, to optimize this. I very confused if i should order it at all?

```
  var sites = (from site in context.Sites
               select new
               {
                   Site = site,
                   Cam1 = context.Photos.Any(p => p.SiteId == site.SiteID && p.PhotoNumber == 1),
                   Cam2 = context.Photos.Any(p => p.SiteId == site.SiteID && p.PhotoNumber == 2),
                   Cam3 = context.Photos.Any(p => p.SiteId == site.SiteID && p.PhotoNumber == 3)
               }).ToList();
```

I know that the most easy way is probably something like:

```
var sitesToCameraIds = (from photo in context.Photos 
    select new { SiteId = photo.SiteId, CameraId = photo.PhotoNumber})
    .Distinct()
    .ToList().OrderBy(p => p.SiteId);
```

But it will be VERY slow as it needs to check all photos to make distinct on not indexed field `PhotoNumber` (cant be index as far as it can be only 1-3), instead i want to use `Any()` as far as it stop search on first match.

Photo table:

[image]

Site table:

[image]

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Do you want to know if a Site as Photos that are 1,2 and 3?  It sounds like you do, then your questions talks about sorting on a date which there is no code example of nor any reason to know about dates that I can tell.

Comment: @Erik Philips i add tables picture. I want to know as example if site with SiteId = 10 have only Photos with PhotoNumber = 1 only or it have any Photos with PhotoNumber = 1 and PhotoNumber = 2

Comment: Do what does any of the dates have to do with anything?

Comment: Dates used in other parts, i was think ordering by date will increase Any() perfomance. Probably im wrong.

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. `Any` will use `SiteID` FK column which should be indexed. The problem is that 3 `Any` will generate 3 `EXISTS` subqueries.

Comment: If you are using EF, you should have a navigation (collection)  property from sites to photos - do you? Note: If you have no information about the distribution of `PhotoNumber`, ordering is of no help.

Comment: if the problem is that `PhotoNumber` isn't indexed there is one obvious improvement. Also, what about data integrity? Is it safe to assume that the photo's are always uniformly numbered (i.e.only 1,2,3, beginning at 1)? If so, you can simply count the number of photos per site.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get know if Site have any Photos with PhotoNumber = 1, 2 and
>   3

```
var photoNumbers = new List<int> {1,2,3}

var isSiteHasAnyPhotos = context
  .Photos
  .Any(p => p.SiteId = siteId && photoNumbers.Contains(q.PhotoNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join once and pivot the results if you only want to know if each of the photos exist for every site:

```
var sites =
    from site in context.Sites
    join photo in context.Photos on site.Id equals photo.SiteId into photos
    from photo in photos.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group photo by site into g
    select new
    {
        Site = g.Key,
        HasPhotoNumber1 = g.Any(x => x.PhotoNumber == 1),
        HasPhotoNumber2 = g.Any(x => x.PhotoNumber == 2),
        HasPhotoNumber3 = g.Any(x => x.PhotoNumber == 3)
    };
```

Performing a single `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will be more efficient and ensure that sites without any photos are still returned in the results.

Also, make sure that `SiteId` is indexed. For example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Photos] ON [Photos]
(
   [SiteId] ASC,
   [PhotoNumber] ASC
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an EF navigation property from `Sites` to `Photos` to provide a join for you, you can manually do the join:

```
var sites = (from site in context.Sites
             join p in context.Photos on site.SiteID equals p.SiteId into pj
             select new {
                 Site = site,
                 Cam1 = pj.Any(p => p.PhotoNumber == 1),
                 Cam2 = pj.Any(p => p.PhotoNumber == 2),
                 Cam3 = pj.Any(p => p.PhotoNumber == 3)
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer might have been appropriate for LINQ to Objects (and  even for EF Core, who knows). However in EF6 it generates exactly the same SQL as the original query of OP, thus makes no any difference. Same if navigation property is used instead of the group join. A good example of how you cannot simply apply a general principle to a concrete scenario.

Comment: I am impressed that EF/LINQ to SQL converts `into pj` into a sub-select query and doesn't pass through the join. Hopefully the SQL Server will create an efficient plan.